# in C#, Is there good way for several initializer of collections with several types?

Tags: c#

I have a dataset, like

```
class DataSet
{
  List<int> IntList;
  List<int> IntList2;
  List<string> StringList;
  // ...and many other lists with many types
}
```

And I have to write several initializers like

```
class InitializerLocalFileSync
{
  void Load(DataSet d)
  {
    LoadSync(d.IntList);
    LoadSync(d.IntList2);
    LoadSync(d.StringList);
    // ... and many initilization methods
  }
}

class InitializerLocalFileAsync
{
  async Task Load(DataSet d)
  {
    await LoadAsync(d.IntList);
    await LoadAsync(d.IntList2);
    await LoadAsync(d.StringList);
    // ... and many initilization methods, too
  }
}

class InitializerDownloadFromWWW // there is some variant like this, cause of I have many data providers
{
}
```

It works good, but there are many duplicated codes, so when DataSet's members added or removed, I should fix all implemented initializers. DataSet is very often changes and I'm tired to fix that initializers. Is there a sweeter way to write this?

Comment: What does the Load methods do? If its just Deserialize from somewhere write something that serializes a Dataset and not the individual lists.

Comment: _"DataSet is very often changes"_ - it shouldn't. If you need to adapt _the code_ very frequently, maybe you need something more flexible? In that you can handle different content, without changing the code.

Comment: @Ralf It just deserializes json/csv but in my case the list and file should matches 1 by 1, because of that file is not made by me..

Comment: To many unknowns. Might be helpful to implement this as Dictionary of those lists but that's just a guess. Or a code generator for that Dataset that just selects the correct templates to use for the different ListTypes and generates fitting DataSet Code.

Comment: Your code is pretty generic, so any advice that can be given would be pretty generic too. I would recommend to look into moving some parts of the initialization code into `DataSet` class itself, thus reducing duplication. For example, you can create a method `IEnumerable<string> GetAllListProperties()` there that will return `"IntList1", "IntList2", "StringList", ...` and then something like `LoadList(string listName, object data) { ... }` that will perform the work. Then you only need to call each of these methods in your initializers and any further changes you will make only in `DbSet`.